Local maxima/minima, with one sided limit
I'm self learning calculus. Should $(1,2)$ be a local maximum, and $(-1, 0)$ a local minimum? (according to solution manual, these are local maximum and minimum, resp.)
I'm not sure if endpoint definition of local extrema applies here, as $x=-1$ or $1$ are not endpoints.


The answer in these edge cases depends on the precise wording of the definition of "local minimum (maximum)" in your text. Whether or not they are called such is independent of understanding what the graph looks like - which you do.
I would rather not call the point at $(-1,0)$ a local minimum since there are values of $x$ near $-1$ where the value of the function is smaller. Your text may differ.
I wouldn't call $(1,2)$ a local maximum even if you defined the value of the function there to be $2$ rather than $3$.
None of this discussion is about the function, it's about the vocabulary we define to talk about the function. People who use different vocabulary should agree about how the underlying mathematical objects behave.

What about (1,2). Would you call it a local maximum?

@patentfox See my edit.

This is my first comment in this forum...

The primary focus is on determining the tangents passing through points.
Stationary points occur when the tangent of the curve is horizontal. Among these, the lowest and highest points are termed Local Minimum and Local Maximum respectively, or global if there's an asymptote.
In this case, points $(1,2)$ and $(-1,0)$ are not stationary points as their tangents are vertical, leading to an undefined slope (If you attempt to solve the limit, the result is infinity).
Examining the graph, the highest (and lowest) stationary points correspond to the peak of the first curve and the bottom of the second curve. To determine their x-coordinate, you'll need to obtain a function, differentiate it, and analyze its sign. Subsequently, you can find the y-coordinate by evaluating the function with the obtained x-coordinate.

Maxima and minima (local or global) are more general than stationary points. The absolute value function has a minimum at $0$, but no derivative there.

It's possible to have local minimum/maximum when slope is undefined, e.g. at a corner. However, my question is about discontinuity.
